Mount path change automatically in Ubuntu
I have two HDD connected and I am using Ubuntu.
The mount path of them automatically changed

/media/talha/data1 from /media/talha/data
/media/talha/New Volume1 from  /media/talha/New\ Volume

I have tried mounting and un mounting as follow but that did not worked
sudo umount /media/talha/data1
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/talha/data
sudo umount /media/talha/New\ Volume1
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/talha/New\ Volume

I read on different forums that i need to make it permanent via fstab but i am not sure how to do that.
Here is more details
lsblk
sda           8:0    1   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1    16M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    1 878.9G  0 part /media/talha/data1
└─sda3        8:3    1 984.1G  0 part /media/talha/New Volume1
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 

blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p5: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="264EB3D04EB39751" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f10b9e11-8c58-4464-877d-1bc602e82a19"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="6EA27EABA27E7803" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c449080c-e4a9-4efb-8745-e7f6429f130e"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="507A-F76D" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="f5dcabbd-c7d3-4e42-a4b1-2bcafe036613"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="a53981dd-8786-452a-9774-91d9ec04716e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="869dc4cb-b0e3-4faa-a3c6-c527d16aadbc"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="688a6f56-855c-452a-aa68-5b2f871073bb" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d171b8b8-59d4-4cbe-81c3-b895e8b44966"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="data" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="50C6ED99C6ED8018" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="1770d5cb-55d8-451d-a78e-d34f985e08b3"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="8C48F0EC48F0D5C4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c3f9c251-74f2-4e33-a2f6-fbab1f739f93"

sudo nano /etc/fstab
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=a53981dd-8786-452a-9774-91d9ec04716e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=507A-F76D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

EDIT
I added these line in fstab
UUID=50C6ED99C6ED8018 "/media/talha/data" ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID=8C48F0EC48F0D5C4 "/media/talha/New Volume" ntfs defaults 0 0

then sudo mount -a
and got this error
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 14 -- ignored
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

When i do
sudo fuser -m /media/talha/New\ Volume
I got a huge list of
/media/talha/New Volume:     1rce     2rc     3rc     4rc     5r
EDIT
Issue resolved

Restart the operating system
unmount both partition
handle space in New Voume fix the issue

UUID=50C6ED99C6ED8018 /media/talha/data ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID=8C48F0EC48F0D5C4 /media/talha/New\040Volume ntfs defaults 0 0


no, i am unable to eject my New\ Volume drive

Is /dev/sda an internal drive?  Is your problem solved?

The location /media/ is meant for external drives, DVD, etc. not permanent internal drives.

yes, thanks a lot

Please don't put the answer inside the question. Either answer your own question and accept that or another answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Does this answer your question? Avoid adding numbers to USB disks partition label/UUID when mount point exists under /media/user

The reason a second mount point is created may be because in a previous moment, the drive was not correctly unmounted. Then the mount point is not erased. Next time you want to mount that drive, Ubuntu increments the name of the mount point, because an older one is still there.
To prevent that from happening, make sure the drive is correctly unmounted each time:

Only unplug a drive after the system fully has shutdown

or

Unmount using the button in the file manager before unplugging the drive.

To resolve the current situation:

Make sure no drives are connected
Remove any remaining directory under your /media/$USER directory. You will need administrative permissions to do that.

Next time, a drive again should be automatically mounted on its default mount point.
